# Construction of the necklace by homotopy type theory

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

The necklace can be obtained from a circle by attaching $n$ 2-spheres $S^2$ along arcs, so the necklace $N(n,S^1,a_i)$ is homotopy equivalent to the space obtained by attaching $n$ 2-spheres $S^2$ to a circle $S^1$ at points $a_i$ where $i \in [1,n]$. My question is how to construct the necklace $N(n,S^1,a_i)$ in homotopy type theory.

Comment: Can you include how you might set up notation for this in homotopy type theory, to set some conventions for answers?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be

```
Inductive Necklace (n:nat) :=
| strand : Circle -> Necklace
| bead : forall (k:nat), k<n -> Sphere2 -> Necklace
| attach : forall (k:nat) (p:k<n), strand base = bead k p base2.
```